Where can I find the baggage allowance information that is legally binding?
I'm looking at some "e-ticket itinerary/receipt" issued by Korean Air for a flight from the United States to Asia. I read the baggage information section and it says:

Information above is provided for referencial use.

which means that whatever information it contains, it might be incorrect and I would have to pay the price for any incorrectness. (e.g., if it says that the maximum weight is 23 kg but in fact it's 20 kg then I'll have to pay some extra fee).
This makes me wonder: where can I find the baggage allowance information that is legally binding (i.e., if the check-in staff disagrees with that  information, then it's their problem, not mine)? E.g., is the baggage allowance information  on the Korean Air website for checked baggage and carry-on baggage legally binding?

Ticket:


Note that even if it's "their problem" in some legal sense, they can certainly make it your problem in the short term, by simply refusing to carry your baggage.  You might in principle be able to sue them for any resulting damages, but the resolution would happen long after your vacation or business trip had been ruined.

@NateEldredge thanks, agreed.

And legal binging is difficult. IIRC in the generic rules of aviation, they can refuse baggage on any reason, if it is for safety (no space on the plane). It it similar that they can refuse passengers (e.g. if a seatbelt broke and so not safe to have the passenger). Law is complex and there is (nearly always) a contradictory rule (if you look at details) or more generic rules which take precedence (if you are rich, so with a good lawyer, it is your card "free from prison"

@FranckDernoncourt - nothing is binding with airlines :/

quite right @GiacomoCatenazzi  ..

Look for the Contract of Carriage posted on the airline's website (example for Korean Air).  This is the legally binding agreement between you and the airline.
It should cover limitations on baggage weight.  However, it might not include the actual numbers, but might refer to something like "limits stated on the airline website" or "on the itinerary".  If so, then those limits are in fact legally binding.

Thanks, I looked at Korean Air's Contract of Carriage (https://www.koreanair.com/contents/footer/terms-and-policies/terms-of-carriage -> international), it says "The limit on the number and the size of free baggage allowance
can be found on flight tickets and the Korean Air website.". But the ticket says the information is not binding. I don't know whether the information on the website is binding.

Binding, but Article 9 (for International passengers) allows a lot of extra freedom to airlines.. So to Frank: use your brain: avoid airlines which are known to be more arbitrary then others (reputation is a value, which we may pay more)

Baggage rules are highly dependent and the fare class, the specific ticket rules, and how the ticket is bought. I've never seen a Contract of Carriage including that level of detail, so it's unlikely that you find anything useful or actionable in there. I

And with connecting flights, rules became more complex: depending on the main leg.
